# Adding a simple TagHelper causes this error: "RenderBody has not been called for the page "

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

[Code available here](https://github.com/ciaran036/coresample)

In an ASP.NET Core 3.0 web application, I have added the following simple tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("submit-button")]
public class SubmitButtonTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Submit";
    public string Classes { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(
            $@"<span class=""btn btn-primary {Classes}"" id=""{Id}"">{Title}</span>");
    }
}
```

Which I intend to use like this:

```
<submit-button></submit-button>
```

However, the act of adding the SubmitButtonTagHelper without even attempting to use it results in the following runtime exception:

> InvalidOperationException: RenderBody has not been called for the page
>   at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'. To ignore call IgnoreBody().

I have imported the tag helpers by adding this line to the Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, Web
```

My _Layout.cshtml page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><vc:product-name></vc:product-name> @ViewData["Title"]</title>

    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)

    <partial name="_FrameworkStyles" />
</head>
<body class="top-navigation">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
            <div class="">
                <vc:Navigation></vc:Navigation>

                @RenderBody()

                <div class="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <partial name="_FrameworkScripts" />

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

How am I going wrong here? On debugging, I can see that the a breakpoint is being hit in the SubmitButtonTagHelper but yet I haven't referenced it anywhere? It was my understanding that the [HtmlTargetElement] attribute would mean it would only apply where the element tag was "submit-button". Is that not correct?

I have one other tag helper in my project and I also noticed that the breakpoint in that class is also being hit in places where I haven't referenced it.

I'm surely doing something silly, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core MVC has the concept of [Tag Helper Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components):

> A Tag Helper Component is a Tag Helper that allows you to conditionally modify or add HTML elements from server-side code.
>
> ...
>
> Tag Helper Components don't require registration with the app in *_ViewImports.cshtml*.
>
> ...
>
> Two common use cases of Tag Helper Components include:
>
> 1. [Injecting a <link> into the <head>.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components#inject-into-html-head-element)
> 2. [Injecting a <script> into the <body>.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components#inject-into-html-body-element)

Also from the docs, here's an implementation of a Tag Helper Component:

> ```
> public class AddressStyleTagHelperComponent : TagHelperComponent
> {
>     private readonly string _style = 
>         @"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""/css/address.css"" />";
>
>     public override int Order => 1;
>
>     public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context,
>                                       TagHelperOutput output)
>     {
>         if (string.Equals(context.TagName, "head", 
>                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
>         {
>             output.PostContent.AppendHtml(_style);
>         }
>
>         return Task.CompletedTask;
>     }
> }
> ```

Once this is registered (shown next), `AddressStyleTagHelperComponent` will run twice: once for the `head` element; once for the `body` element. Here's how it's registered with DI:

> ```
> services.AddTransient<ITagHelperComponent, AddressScriptTagHelperComponent>();
> ```

At this point (or perhaps even earlier), you're likely thinking I've gone mad. What does any of this have to do with `SubmitButtonTagHelper`?

Through its inheritence tree, `SubmitButtonTagHelper` ends up implementing [`ITagHelperComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.itaghelpercomponent). If you were to add the following DI registration, `SubmitButtonTagHelper` would run as a Tag Helper Component, once for `head` and once for `body`:

> ```
> services.AddTransient<ITagHelperComponent, SubmitButtonTagHelper>();
> ```

`SubmitButtonTagHelper` is destructive, replacing the entire contents of the element it operates on. If it were to replace the content of a `body` element, the body would, of course, lose its `RenderBody` directive.

So, that's a long explanation of what *could* happen if `SubmitButtonTagHelper` were registered as a Tag Helper Component. It shouldn't be too surprising that that's exactly what's happening in the sample you've uploaded to GitHub ([source](https://github.com/ciaran036/coresample/blob/master/DependencyInjection/AutofacConfig.cs#L28-L32)):

> ```
> private static void WebRegistration(ContainerBuilder builder)
> {
>     builder.RegisterAutowiredAssemblyInterfaces(Assembly.Load(Web));
>     builder.RegisterAutowiredAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(Web));
> }
> ```

I don't know much about Autofac, but it's clear that the call to `RegisterAutowiredAssemblyInterfaces` shown above finds `SubmitButtonTagHelper` and registers it against all of its interfaces, including `ITagHelperComponent`.

Again, I don't know much about Autofac, but, ultimately, Tag Helpers that aren't intended to run as Tag Helper Components should be excluded from this auto-registration process. Here's a suggestion for how to do this filtering, although I expect it's a terrible Autofac approach:

```
builder.RegisterAutowiredAssemblyInterfaces(Assembly.Load(Web))
    .Where(x => !x.Name.EndsWith("TagHelper"));
```